# Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) with a large number of short texts and a small number of long texts

Tags: python, nlp, lda

I am trying to generate comparable topics from a large number of short texts and a relatively small number of long texts. Currently, I mix them into one corpus to run LDA. I found that most topics are driven by short texts given that the number of short texts is much larger than the number of long documents. I have 2 questions:
(1) Can anyone help explain this issue (i.e., the dominance of topics from short texts) theoretically?
(2) Is there a better way to deal with long texts and short texts at the same time? I am thinking of using short texts as a training sample and long texts as the testing sample. Is it theoretically correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can break the long text into sentences and use them along with the short texts. You can then average the sentence topics for the long text.